# Single Page Application and $(window).bind('load', function() {....}

Tags: jquery

I use this code to load an image gallery by binding it when window has completely loaded within a Single Page Application:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    console.log("window loaded");
    $("div#gallery").slideViewerPro({
        autoslide: true,
        thumbsVis: false,
        galBorderWidth: 1,
        galBorderColor: "#003f00"
    });
});
```

This event is only valid whenever the window has loaded and in the case of a Single Page Application this event has only one callback right and this is only after the window has been loaded? whenever there is a change within my page the callback of $(window).bind(......) is never been invoked again?! What is more appropriate in Single Page Applications to ask for changes in content with jQuery for instance. Is there a haschange() or a dom_has_loaded() in jQuery?

I hope I pointed it out clearly.

Comment: What sort of change would you expect to invoke the load callback again? The load event only gets fired with the page is loaded initially or refreshed.

Comment: Also, for something like `dom_has_loaded()`, are you looking for jQuery's `$(document).ready(...);`? See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for details.

Comment: whenever I have a second or a third gallery invoked with only the code above I only see the gallery once because it is invoked only after the window has loaded... are you sure that $(window).bind('load', function() {....}); is also working when the site only gets refreshed? To me it seems not so...

Comment: I intend to see a gallery within <div id="gallery"> which is invoked on each site there is a gallery included but I assume that after the window has been loaded the gallery is never invoked again...Am I right? I use slideview pro 1.5 - It must have something to do with the event callback of $(window).bind....

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in jQuery that will do what you are trying to do. It would require either DOM Mutation Events which may not be supported in all browsers or a setInterval which is not efficient.

Instead, bind a custom event to the window and trigger the event when you change the content of the page.

```
$(window).bind("contentChanged load",function(){
    console.log("window loaded or changed");
    $("#gallery").slideViewerPro({ // div#gallery is very inefficient
        autoslide: true,
        thumbsVis: false,
        galBorderWidth: 1,
        galBorderColor: "#003f00"
    });
});
```

and later on:

```
$("#content").load("somepage.php",function(){
    $(window).trigger("contentChanged");
});
```

Comment: The load of my to be changed content is invoked with sammy? Does this make any difference in that solution you offering me?

this.get('#/index', function(context) {  
        $.get('stueble.html', function (data) {
  context.app.swap(data);
                $(window).trigger("contentChanged");
 });
});

this code happens within document.ready - the window.bind for sammy happens at the top of my script.